# mail not sending when add cc in php mail function

Tags: php

Hi i am using php mail function .When i add cc header in my code then mail is not going and when i commented the cc header line then mail is sent out. how can i send the mail to the cc person.
this is my code.

```
<?php

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: ABC <abc@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: axyz@gmail.com' . "\r\n";

$done = mail('abc@gmail.com', 'Test subject', 'Test body', $headers);

if ($done)
    echo 'DONE';
else
    echo 'NOT DONE';
?>
```

Comment: maybe your ISP is preventing you from send emails.

Comment: Your codes works for me.

Comment: Do you have any warnings? Check your error.log.

Comment: The CC: is just a header, it does not affect where the mail is sent to.

Answer (score 0):

just remove dot(.) symbol before \r\n and also double quotes. For instance:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n';
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n';

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: ABC <abc@gmail.com>\r\n';
$headers .= 'Cc: axyz@gmail.com\r\n';
```

Try the above code, should work.